# Loop through different Matlab structures

Tags: matlab

A graph is represented by two things, a set of `nodes` V and a set of `edges` U, as pairs `[1 2]` connecting the node `1` to the node `2` in V.

Now, I have a graph and its set of tops/nodes:

```
V = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
```

and its edges:

```
U = {[1 6],[2 3],[3 5],[2 4],[5 1]};
```

How can I write for loop to check if top number 1 `V(1)` is connected with top number 2 `V(2)`, on the edge's list `U`?

---

Background behind the motive for this question

1. I need to find if graph is bipartite using Matlab.
2. Because I need to disjoint these two tops in separate sets.

Comment: I don't understand if there is no edge between them so there is no connection. no ?

Comment: This is not the place to solve your homeworks. Please show us what you have tried so far, or at least your approach.

Comment: @Chris311 I didn't ask for whole solving. I just needed 1 function, which I wasn't able to write because of poor knowledge of Matlab. I will try to improve my questions next time. Thanks

Comment: @Chris311 Judging by the answer it seems this is the place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I write for loop to check if top number 1 is connected with top number 2?

Here is the function for it. Create a file named `areConnect.m` and put it on it:

```
function areConnected = areConnect( topA, topB, U )

    for i = 1 : numel( U )

        vector = cell2mat( U(i) );

        if topA == vector(1) && topB == vector(2)

            areConnected = true;
            return

        end

        if topB == vector(1) && topA == vector(2)

            areConnected = true;
            return

        end

    end

    areConnected = false;

end
```

---

Here on your main program you may test it:

```
V = [1 2 3 4 5 6]
U = {[1 6],[2 3],[3 5],[2 4],[5 1]}

areConnected16 = areConnect( V(1), V(6), U )
areConnected12 = areConnect( V(1), V(2), U )
```

It would result in the following output:

```
V =
     1     2     3     4     5     6
U = 
    [1x2 double]    [1x2 double]    [1x2 double]    [1x2 double]    [1x2 double]
areConnected16 =
     1
areConnected12 =
     0
```

References:

1. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html
2. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/specialcharacters.html